# How can I store the sub arrays of an array without taking elements next to each other?

Tags: c#, arrays, sub-array

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter your number of array inputs");
        int numberofarray = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        int[] array = new int[numberofarray];

        Console.WriteLine("Enter the values of the array");

        for(int i=0; i<numberofarray;i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter {0} . number", i + 1);
            array[i] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        }


        createsubarray(array);

    }

    static void createsubarray(int[] array)
    {
        int[,] subarray = new int[Convert.ToInt32(Math.Pow(2, array.Length)-1), array.Length]; 


        int counter = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
        {

            for (int j = i; j<=array.Length; j++)
            {

                for(int k = i; k<j; k++)
                {                      
                      subarray[counter, k] = array[k];     
                }

                counter++;

            }

        }

        for (int m = 0; m < subarray.GetLength(0); m++)
        {
            for (int l = 0; l < subarray.GetLength(1); l++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(subarray[m, l]);
            }

            Console.WriteLine();
        }


    }
```

I was able to store sub arrays but I dont know how not to store empty sub arrays and that if the one element is stored, the next one won't be stored. For example;

array = {1,2,3,4,5}

sub arrays should be like this = {1,3,5},{1,3},{1,5},{2,4},{3,5}

Comment: Unclear what you are asking

Comment: I just wrote it as an example so I didnt write down the all the sub arrays. if the array is {1,2,3,4,5}, sub arrays are {1,3,5},{1,3},{1,4},{1,5},{2,4},{2,5},{3,5}. So array[i] and array[i+1] shouldnt be in the same sub array.

Comment: So are you looking to output **all** permutations/combinations of a given array? or just some magic subset

Comment: We can count as magic subset. It is not all permutations/combinations of a given array. For {2,1,3,4,5}, it should be like {2,3,5},{2,3},{2,4},{2,5},{1,4},{1,5},{3,5}

Comment: **Why** do you want this?

Comment: Please update your question to show both example inputs and **full** results for each of them.

Comment: Can the input array have duplicate values in it (i.e. could it be {1,1,3,4,5})?